# Sane value for net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog in sysctl.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sysctl

I'm tuning `sysctl.conf`.

According to an [optimization guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/configure-nginx-for-optimized-performance) on linode's website, the following is a sane value to set in `sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 3240000
```

However, the [same value](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sysctl) in an archlinux optimization guide is:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65536
```

Lastly, on another [optimization blog](https://russ.garrett.co.uk/2009/01/01/linux-kernel-tuning/) (that is old but still SEOs quite high on Google), the value is touted to be:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
```

All these ball parks are wildly different. What's the reasoning behind setting this value to a high number (vs a low number)? Which one should is the actual 'sane' value to start with?

Comment: Whats your somaxconn / rtt / connection duration? Have you got syn cookies enabled? In the absence of further info, the linode recommendation seems a bit OTT.

Comment: I've set `net.core.somaxconn = 4096` (but linode is recommending `net.core.somaxconn = 65536`). And yes of course I've set `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1`. Which others do you need?

Comment: Mint (desktop setup) : 128. Debian 8 (server setup) : 256.

Answer (score 16):

It mainly depends on how much traffic you're running through you server(s). There are several important questions:

- How many concurrent connections do you expect to handle?
- What is the average response time? (if generating response takes e.g. 10-50s seconds you might easily run out of resources, even without DDoS attack).
- Which server do you use? `nginx`, `haproxy`, `varnish`

You should be monitoring:

```
netstat -s | grep "SYNs to LISTEN"
```

which is a symptom that your server is dropping packets (because e.g. the backlog queue is full).

Netstat statistics are exported to `/proc/net/netstat` where the stat is called `ListenDrops`. It might be easier to parse with a script, or use something like:

```
cat /proc/net/netstat | awk '(f==0) { i=1; while ( i<=NF) {n[i] = $i; i++ }; f=1; next} \
    (f==1){ i=2; while ( i<=NF){ printf "%s = %d\n", n[i], $i; i++}; f=0}'
```

to get human readable names of stats. You should be able to collect this data using e.g. [telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/nstat), [collectd](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Protocols) or [prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/collector/netstat_linux.go).

## Kernel tuning

`net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog` -  How many half-open connections for which the client has not yet sent an ACK response can be kept in the queue [(source)](https://medium.com/@pawilon/tuning-your-linux-kernel-and-haproxy-instance-for-high-loads-1a2105ea553e).

`net.core.somaxconn` The maximum number of connections that can be queued for acceptance

`net.core.netdev_max_backlog` The maximum number of packets in the receive queue that passed through the network interface and are waiting to be processed by the kernel.

These settings are tightly connected with number of opened files (as in Linux each new connection will open 2 file handles). You can check your limits using:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
8160    0       3270712
```

Which means that the server has `8160` opened files out of `3270712`.